# How to draw 3D circles/ring in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I need to draw something like this in a RealityKit app. I would prefer not to use a 3rd party lib.

[image]

as the radius could be from a couple of meters to about one hundred meter, I like to be flexible in how thick/wide and high the "border" can be. I guess to produce the model in code is the only way to ensure the extruded part looks always good. If I would import a usdz with fix dimensions it would look strange after scaling.

In Apples SceneKit if found the SCNShape which takes a 2D path and extrudes to a 3D Model. But I have no idea how to implement this SCNGeometry in my existing session which already contains models from usdz files and other ModelEntities. As far as I know SceneKit and RealityKit are not compatible. I thought somehow I could get the mesh from the SCNGeometry and build a new ModelEntity from this. But this seems to be impossible.

I am relatively new to all of this and the SceneKit, ARKit, RealityKit, ... is still overwhelming or confusing I should say. I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks